# Porting C code to Arduino Platform (Errors in struct and typedef definitions)

Tags: c, struct, typedef, arduino

I have a working cross-platform visual studio windows C console application source. This application communicates with a RFID reader using serial interface.  I want to port it to a microcontroller to start reader without PC. For this purpose I decide to use Arduino. It uses C/C++ syntax.  In the below code Arduino IDE compiler gives error. The error is 
**"error: expected `)' before '*' token"**.

```
/* A typedef that should be used for RFID radio handles */
typedef HANDLE32    RFID_RADIO_HANDLE;

/******************************************************************************
 * Name: RFID_PACKET_CALLBACK_FUNCTION
 *
 * Description:
 *   The tag-protocol operation response packet callback function signature.
 *
 * Parameters:
 *   handle - the handle for the radio for which operation response packets are
 *     being returned
 *   bufferLength - the length of the buffer that contains the packets
 *   pBuffer - a buffer that contains one or more complete operation response
 *     packets
 *   context - an application-defined context value that was supplied when the
 *     the original tag-protocol operation function was invoked
 *
 * Returns:
 *   0 - continue making packet callbacks
 *   !0 - cancel the tag-protocol operation and stop making callbacks for that
 *
 *   The return value of the last packet callback for the tag-protocol operation
 *   is returned to the application if the application indicates the desire for
 *   this value when it invokes the tag-protocol opreation.
 ******************************************************************************/
typedef INT32S (RFID_CALLBACK * RFID_PACKET_CALLBACK_FUNCTION)(
    RFID_RADIO_HANDLE   handle,
    INT32U              bufferLength,
    const INT8U*        pBuffer,
    void*               context
    );
```

It is working in visual studio, so its syntax should be correct. I do not know how to solve this error.

I have another error in below code. There are lots of struct definitons in this header. I give small part of it which gives error. The error is **"error: 'RFID_PACKET_CALLBACK_FUNCTION' does not name a type"**.

```
.
.
.
...
typedef struct {
    INT32U                 tagStopCount;
    RFID_PACKET_CALLBACK_FUNCTION           pCallback;
    void*                     context;
    INT32S*                 pCallbackCode;
} RFID_18K6C_COMMON_PARMS;

typedef struct {
    INT32U                  length;
    INT32U                  command;
    RFID_PACKET_CALLBACK_FUNCTION           pCallback;
    void*                      context;
    INT32S*                  pCallbackCode;
} RFID_ISSUE_RADIO_COMMAND_PARMS;

typedef struct {
    INT32U                  length;
    INT32U                  duration;
    RFID_PACKET_CALLBACK_FUNCTION           pCallback;
    void*                      context;
    INT32S*                  pCallbackCode;
} RFID_RANDOM_CW_PARMS;
.
.
.
...
```

These codes are all working in VS console application. What sould I do for Arduino platform?

Comment: More code would be helpful, including any libraries if any?

Comment: I do not want to add a full library, it is too long (880 lines) and it has only similar struct definitons.

Answer (score 4):

Your first problem is that the function pointer syntax for the `typedef` of `RFID_PACKET_CALLBACK_FUNCTION` is incorrect. This bit:

```
(RFID_CALLBACK * RFID_PACKET_CALLBACK_FUNCTION)
```

should define the function type, but the code as given isn't a valid type identifier. The fact that it works in Visual Studio does not guarantee syntactic correctness because compiler writers almost always support syntactic extensions to control arcane features, and Microsoft are certainly guilty of that. However in this case it doesn't look like something compiler-specific, and I would guess there's a header file somewhere doing a conditional `#define RFID_CALLBACK ...` that isn't happening correctly in the Arduino environment. (Arduino isn't proper C, and its preprocessor is [reportedly](http://softsolder.com/2009/10/06/arduino-be-careful-with-the-preprocessor/) not fully featured.)

Your second problem is just a consequence of the first, since if that `typedef` fails then `RFID_PACKET_CALLBACK_FUNCTION` indeed doesn't name a type.

As pointed out by freespace, more fundamental than either of those problems is your expectation that you can easily transplant code from a desktop OS to a dinky little Arduino without having to do some serious work.

Comment: Yes I know, if I can solve first error the second one is automatically solved. But nothing comes to mind about this.

Comment: @Ramazan Work out what `RFID_CALLBACK` is supposed to mean, and replace it with the literal equivalent. (My guess is the most likely value is nothing at all, with an outside possibility of something like `*`, but you're the one with the code. Don't just gawp at it, grep it.)

Answer (score 3):

You can not simply walk into Mordor... wait no, wrong fantasy.

You can not simply take the source code of an application intended to run in a fully featured OS, and expect it to magically work on an embedded platform that not only is of a completely different architecture and design, but also extreme limited in hardware resources.

What you need to do is read the source code and understand how to communicate with the RFID card reader. Having obtains this knowledge, you need to then learn how to program an Arduino, either using the Arduino software environment, or a generic AVR environment.

Armed with the knowledge above, you can then implement the required communication protocol on the Arduino platform.

In addition, you will most likely need to learn some basic electronics, as much as you need to properly perform level shifting to conform to the RS-232 serial standard.

This is your quest. Good luck.

Comment: I have already mentioned that the source code is a cross-platform source. It has several header files for both windows environment and embedded environment. This project is said to be compatible with Rabbit brand microcontrollers (which uses Dynamic C), most of the code is ANSI-C so it should be easy to work with Arduino platform. I do not want to use Rabbit microcontrollers.

Comment: The programming language isn't the problem. The problem is that the hardware platforms contain differences that can not be abstracted away by the programming language. That requires a fairly heroic library if nothing else.

Comment: Yes you are right but hardware related part of the code is only serial com API. I have already changed this to fit arduino platform. My problem is, compiler gives errors for that struct and typdef definitons. Can you see any errors on the typedef and struct definitions? Do you have any recommandation for that?

Comment: There is a header file for this, if embedded platform is used header defines them.
typedef float  HANDLE32;
typedef double   HANDLE64;

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your interest. I will try something.